# finding divisor with condition with python using 'if' and 'while'

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

trying to find how many divisors in 120, and printing divisors

```
div_n = 1
count = 0
n = 120

while div_n <= n:
    if n % div_n == 0:
        print(div_n)
        count += 1
    div_n += 1
print('number of divisor that 120 is {}.'.format(count))
```

the output should be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
10
12
15
20
24
30
40
60
120
number of divisor that 120 is 16
```

But the problem I'm trying to solve says the code is not meeting the requirements.
If there is nothing wrong, or more information is needed let me know.

Comment: what's the program actually outputting and how is it different from what it should output? My preference here would be a for loop, but that's just nitpicking

Comment: Please see [ask] and reread your question from the point of view of someone that knows python and number theory sufficiently to answer, but is in no way privy to what is on your screen or in your mind

Comment: Code you post here should run if copy and pasted into a repl. Please fix your code to make that so.

Comment: _"the code is not meeting the requirements"_ what are these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
def get_factors(n):
    ret = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if not n % i:
            ret.append(i)
    return ret

factors = get_factors(120)
print(*factors, sep='\n')
print('Total factors:', len(factors))
```

Output:

```html
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
10
12
15
20
24
30
40
60
120
Total factors: 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, once properly indented, works just fine. So I suspect the requirement you don't meet is that of speed - try the code with `n=120000000`.

When you look for divisors you don't need to check all the numbers from 1 to `n`: just check numbers from 1 to `int(sqrt(n))` - when you find a divisor lower than the square root you have also found a related divisor, greater than the square root. In your example, when you find 2 you also find 60, and so on.

So I would do something like:

```py
def divisors(n):
    divs = []
    divs2 = []
    r = int(sqrt(n))
    for d in range(1,r):
        q,m = divmod(n,d)
        if m == 0:
            divs.append(d)
            divs2.append(q)
    if n % r == 0:
        divs.append(r)
    for d in divs:
        print(d)
    for d in divs2[::-1]:
        print(d)
    print(f'Divisors for {n}: {len(divs)+len(divs2)}')
```

EDIT: there was a small bug - if `n` happened to be a perfect square, my code would count its square root twice. So we better stop at `int(sqrt(n))-1` and handle the square root separately.